# Invalid opcode on mulitplication then division

Tags: solidity

I am trying to calculate a percentage of a certain number, to do so I pass to my contract the numerator and denominator and do the following math:

```
amountToAdvance = (_amount * _numeratorPercentageAdvanced) / _denumeratorPercentageAdvanced;
```

I unfortunately keep getting and invalid opcode error on this specific line.
The numbers I am trying to pass are all uint.

```
_amount = 10000
_numeratorPercentageAdvanced = 8
_denumeratorPercentageAdvanced = 10
```

***UPDATED***

Here is the function where the operation is located:

```
function loan(uint _amount, uint _fee, uint _numeratorPercentageAdvanced, uint _denumeratorPercentageAdvanced) public {         
        loanData.amountETH = _amount;         
        loanData.fee = _fee;                        

        loanState = LoanState.not_funded;         
        loanReceipiant = msg.sender;       

        amountToAdvance = (_amount * _numeratorPercentageAdvanced) / _denumeratorPercentageAdvanced;

        NewLoan(this, loanData.amountETH, loanData.fee);     
    }
```

If I comment the line the code compiles fine.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Code runs fine for me. What data types are the variables?

Comment: all uints like stated in the question

Comment: What happens prior to this line? Perhaps it's just coincidence, and you're repeatedly running out of gas on that line. Just a thought. Don't know for sure. More code would help.

Comment: Its a consturctor function so called right at the creation of the loan, I updated the question above.

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce with the given function. I reconstructed the state variables (the struct, enum, event, etc) based on what you have in the function, but still can't get any error to occur with the input you provided. Have you run it through Remix debugger?

Comment: Ok i have just tried with other inputs and indeed it works, the problem seems to be that for some reason I cant pass it big int, my inputs for _amount and _fees were: web3.toWei(10, 'ether'), web3.toWei(2, 'ether') and that gives me an invalid opcode, if i try with ints with less numbers it all works fine. I am a bit confused why would big numbers not work ?